# Use external API for login, without database

Tags: laravel

For a Laravel 5.8 project, I need to use an external API to connect my users.

I do not need a database but I would like to use Auth::user(), Auth::check() ...

Is it possible to use the session driver rather than the database driver for data persistence ?

I searched a lot but I did not find a convincing answer that respects the best practices, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Laravel Auth guard does not support this behaviour, you will need to add an extra Auth guard for this, take a look at [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-guard-in-laravel--cms-29667) tutorial which dives deep into writing custom guards.